# web-ext SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Tags: npm, firefox, async-await, firefox-addon, web-ext

Just installed `web-ext` tool from Mozilla for Firefox for the first time using docs install guide: `npm install --global web-ext`.

Command does not run. Looks to be latest version `7.11.0` only four days old?

```
$ web-ext --version
file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/bin/web-ext.js:13
await webExt.main(absolutePackageDir);
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
```

`web-ext run` yields the same output as shown.

```
$ npm view web-ext

web-ext@7.11.0 | MPL-2.0 | deps: 32 | versions: 78
A command line tool to help build, run, and test web extensions
https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext

keywords: web, extensions, web extensions, browser extensions, firefox, mozilla, add-ons, google, chrome, opera

bin: web-ext

dist
.tarball: https://registry.npmjs.org/web-ext/-/web-ext-7.11.0.tgz
.shasum: f83a6d46215e56bc484d4ff7560a17f5e48d88dd
.integrity: sha512-EG6YXHITNDJB/h6Rc5FF08eMoN45sZPBBIIlEraBzxJ0RdJZ8Z3xvUUawbDwt+mowfv9X0XRWlLSwdWbRKgojg==                                                                       
.unpackedSize: 565.4 kB
```